# Can you use the iPad to manage your iPod?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, ipod, nas

I am about to get an iPad. My only other apple product is the iPod, and I do not have any windows computer (all Linux).

The iPod has been shelved for some time: I don't sync it very often with my music collection (which is on a NAS).

My question is: can I use the iPad as an interface to sync my iPod with my album collection in the NAS?

Comment: How do you sync your iPad then? You'll need to sync the music at least once to the iPad, or you can subscribe to iTunes Match to make your music collection available in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, but although it is possible to use an iPad separately from any computer, managing an iPod with an iPad is currently impossible. Both the iPad and the iPod require a computer to sync.

(Unless you jailbreak it, and somehow convince the iPod that the iPad is a computer with a registered version of iTunes. But I doubt you would want to risk that.)

Probably the closest you could come to this, is using the iCloud feature to sync photos, and movies across both devices, via your computer, and the internet. This is, however a different matter altogether.